# wordpress child theme does not automatically load single-post_type.php from parent

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, child-theming

For the first time I am trying to setup a wordpress child theme. The parent has a complicated templates for custom post types and `header.php` and footer besides stylesheets and javascript files etc.

The child theme only needs to change the css (for now). My child theme only has `style.css` and `functions.php`.

I already have a single-product.php for a custom post type `product` in the parent theme folder.  That is not getting loaded automatically from the parent. Please suggest what is required to get this working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really the best solution but can help.
Copy `header.php` into the child theme and put your css in the `<head>` section. Remember to enclose your css with `<style>custom-css{...}</style>`